# Operand type clash: smalldatetime is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server

Anyone familiar with this error? Thanks a lot :)

My code:

```
declare @FromDate date 
declare @ToDate date 
set @FromDate = '2017/01/01'
set @ToDate = '2017/02/28'

/*********************** INVOICE DETAILS   **************************************/
--declare @FromDate date 
--declare @ToDate date 
--set @FromDate = '1/1/2017'
--set @ToDate = '2/28/2017'

if object_id('tempdb..#tmpInvoiceDetails') IS NOT NULL
begin
   drop table #tmpInvoiceDetails
end

create table dbo.#tmpInvoiceDetails
    (
        [PurchaseOrderKey] uniqueidentifier,
        [AgreementKey] varchar(40),
        [CreatedDate] datetime, 
        [SalesOrderID] varchar(30),
        [ConfirmedInvoiceNumber] varchar(50),
        [CurrencyCode] varchar(5),
        [ExtendedLineItemAmount] int,
        [ExtendedLineItemAmountUSD] int
    )

insert into dbo.#tmpInvoiceDetails
    (
        [PurchaseOrderKey],
        [AgreementKey],
        [CreatedDate], 
        [SalesOrderID],
        [ConfirmedInvoiceNumber],
        [CurrencyCode],
        [ExtendedLineItemAmount],
        [ExtendedLineItemAmountUSD]
    )       
select
    [CreatedDate], 
    [SalesOrderID],
    [PurchaseOrderKey],
    [AgreementKey],
    [ConfirmedInvoiceNumber],
    [CurrencyCode],
    [ExtendedLineItemAmount],
    [ExtendedLineItemAmountUSD] 
from [dbo].[SalesOrderLineItem]
where [CreatedDate] >= @FromDate
    and [CreatedDAte] < @ToDate

--create index on temp audit table

create nonclustered index [tmpIDX] on [dbo].[#tmpInvoiceDetails] 
(
    [CreatedDate] ASC,
    [PurchaseOrderKey] ASC
)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 31
>   Operand type clash: smalldatetime is incompatible with uniqueidentifier.

I already tried changing the date format but still the same.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: my apologies, I have edited my post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your columns in wrong order:

```
insert into dbo.#tmpInvoiceDetails
    (
        [PurchaseOrderKey],
        [AgreementKey],
        [CreatedDate], 
        ...
select
    [CreatedDate], 
    [SalesOrderID],
    [PurchaseOrderKey],
    ...
```

So, as a result you're inserting CreatedDate into PurchaseOrderKey, SalesOrderID into AgreementKey etc.

Comment: perfect! thank you so much on that! my problem has been solved! thank you sooooooo much! :D